# Divisibility Checker Decimal and Negative Numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get my divisibility checker code to work correctly. It currently only works with whole positive numbers. If the number is a decimal or a negative number the code will not work. I know I need to add some floats, but I do not know where to add them.

```
def divisibility():
        print "+------------------------------------+"
        print "|Welcome to the Divisibility Checker!|"
        print "+------------------------------------+"

        x = raw_input("Please input a number: ")
        num1 = raw_input("Number to start checking at: ")
        num2 = raw_input("Number to end checking at: ")

        print "Divisibility:"
        for i in range(int(num1), int(num2)):
                if (int(i)) % (int(x)) == 0:
                        print str(i) + ": Yes"
                else:
                        pass
divisibility()
```

What I want this to do it basically print what numbers are divisible by that number imputed. So if you input 2.5, and then you want it to check from 1-10 it should return 2.5, 5, 7.5, and 10. Same as if you input -2, and it checks from 0-(-10) it should return -2, -4, -6, -8, and -10.

Comment: How does one check divisibility for a non-integer?

Comment: Sounds like you want *multiples* not divisibility.

Comment: how are you planning on incrementing for float input in your range?

Comment: Can't you just use `range`?  `range(0, 10, 2.5)` or `range(-10, 0, 2)`... (maybe you need `abs(step)`).

Comment: @Justin, when did range start taking a float  for a step?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh... yeah... that... `np.arange`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's examples, it seems that he wants to get all the integer multiples of a number between two ranges. In light of that goal, I have renamed the function `getMultiples`.

```
from math import ceil
from math import floor


def getMultiples(x, num1, num2):
    num1, num2 = min(num1, num2), max(num1, num2)

    lower = ceil(float(num1) / x)
    upper = floor(float(num2) / x)
    lower, upper = min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper)

    for i in range(int(lower), int(upper) + 1):
       print i * x

getMultiples(2.5, 1, 10)
getMultiples(-2, 0, -10)
```

Output:

```
2.5
5.0
7.5
10.0
0
-2
-4
-6
-8
-10
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do as Merlins answer shows but I imagine as a beginner you are more interested in learning than proficiency.

This code is not complete but should give you enough to start with to get close to what you want.

```
def float_range(start, stop, step): # will step in  any range of step passed 1, .5, .1 etc...
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step


def divisibility():
    print "+------------------------------------+"
    print "|Welcome to the Divisibility Checker!|"
    print "+------------------------------------+"

    x = raw_input("Please input a number: ")
    num1 = (raw_input("Number to start checking at: "))
    num2 = (raw_input("Number to end checking at: "))
    if "." in num1:    # if "." is in the num it is a float
        num1 = float(num1)
    else:               # else an int
        num1 = int(num1)
    if "." in num2:
        num2 = float(num2)
    else:
        num2 = int(num2)
    if "." in x:
        x = float(x)
        step=.5     # you will need more conditions to check and set the appropriate step.
    else:
        x = int(x)
        step=1
    print "Divisibility:"

    for i in float_range(num1, num2 + 1,step=step): # add 1 to range to include top end of range
        if i % x == 0:
            print str(i) + ": Yes"

divisibility()
```